# Анимация смайликов в CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация

Много времени потратил на поиск информации о том, чтобы в CSS заставить моргать смайлики с разной периодичностью во времени. Левый смайлик немного быстрее моргает, в отличии от правого.
Под морганием я имею в виду: изменение формы элипсов по оси Y, эмуляция моргания. [image: Смайлики]

Comment: Добавьте пример кода с морганием ...

Answer (score 3):

Цитата из вопроса:

> Под морганием я имею в виду: изменение формы эллипсов по оси Y,
> эмуляция моргания.

Для реализации изменения формы эллипсов по оси `Y` применена анимация `ry`

```
<ellipse cx="70" cy="35" ry="10" rx="12" fill="black" >
    <animate attributeName="ry" dur="1s" begin="gr1.click" keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" values="10;0;5;0;10" repeatCount="1" /> 
</ellipse>
```

Неравномерность моргания обеспечивают параметры `keyTimes` и `values`
**Обратите внимание:**
количество значений в обоих атрибутах должно быть одинаковым, в данном примере их по пять значений.

Можно делать иконки любой формы.

В примере ниже квадратная иконка, у которой моргает правый глаз и круглая иконка, как на скриншоте в вопросе.

*Анимация начинается при клике по иконке*

```html
<svg  id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    
     width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
                <!-- Прямоугольнрая иконка -->
<g id="gr1"> 
<rect id="rect" x="10" y="0" rx="15" width="85" height="100" fill="gold" />
 
<ellipse cx="35" cy="35" ry="10" rx="12" fill="black" >
 </ellipse>  
                  <!-- Правый глаз  -->
<ellipse cx="70" cy="35" ry="10" rx="12" fill="black" >
    <animate attributeName="ry" dur="1s" begin="gr1.click" keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" values="10;0;5;0;10" repeatCount="1" /> 
</ellipse>

<circle cx="52.5" cy="50" r="30" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dashoffset="-6" stroke-dasharray="80 108.49" />
</g>

               <!-- Круглая иконка -->

<g id="gr2"> 
<circle cx="150" cy="50"  r="46"  stroke="#FE411E" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="6" />
                         <!-- Левый глаз  -->
    <ellipse cx="148" cy="34" ry="16" rx="8" fill="#FE411E" >  
            <animate attributeName="ry" dur="1s" begin="gr2.click" keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" values="15;0;5;0;15" repeatCount="1" />   
  </ellipse>
                         <!-- Правый глаз  -->
     <ellipse cx="170" cy="34" ry="15" rx="6" fill="#FE411E" > 
          <animate attributeName="ry" dur="1s" begin="gr2.click" keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" values="15;0;5;0;15" repeatCount="1" /> 
      </ellipse>  
                         <!-- Рот -->
      <ellipse cx="152" cy="75" ry="5" rx="6" fill="#FE411E" > 
         <animate attributeName="rx" dur="1s" begin="gr2.click" keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" values="6;12;2;12;6" repeatCount="1" /> 
      </ellipse>
 </g>     
</svg>
```